# "Expected statement" error after If-Then-Else

Tags: windows, if-statement, scripting, vbscript

I'm really new to windows scripting so it may seems stupid to some of you. Please bear with me.

```
If IsNull(objUser.Groups) then
    WriteoutputtoCSV(" ")
Else 
    temp = ""
    Set colGroups = objUser.Groups
    For Each objGroup in colGroups
        temp = temp+", "+objGroup.CN
        WriteoutputtoCSV(temp)
End If
```

When I run this, it keep telling me

> error:expected statement

what did I do wrong? I tried to add parentheses after `Else` and before `End If` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It says the error happens on the last line.

Comment: BTW, where did you see this referred to as "windows scripting"? It's VBSCRIPT. Also, if you're starting out in scripting for windows, then you should look into PowerShell.

Comment: It's my second day dealing with it. My boss told me its called windows scripting...sry if that confuses you...Where is a good place to look into if I need vbscript reference?

Comment: It's really ancient stuff, but see [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6.aspx). Do yourself a favor, though, and learn [Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

...I forgot the "NEXT"... Never mind, it is really simple.